# why is emulator killed whenever i tried running the device?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know it have been asked many times but this time i tried many things such as reinstall android studio, update android studio, change the graphics and so on,but it occured everytime.
Here I will also provide my coding if any mistakes were made that may have any relation with my emulator got killed.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="PSIS"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="212dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="Enter Name"
    android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
    android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="#ffff299f"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Attempts Left:"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview"
    android:text="login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview"
    android:text="Cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.task;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static String EXTRA_TEXT;
Button b1, b2;
EditText ed1, ed2;

TextView tx1;
int counter = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (ed1.getText().toString().equals("mohdnoor") &&
                    ed2.getText().toString().equals("123456")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                String text = editText1.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
                 else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                counter--;
                tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                if (counter == 0) {
                    b1.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }




    });


    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
    android:text="!!WELCOME!!"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**secondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.task;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class secondActivity extends Activity {
 Button b1;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView1.setText(text);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Does your emulator get killed for this project or it crashes for any project that you create on Android Studio?

Comment: @Aditya only for this project apparently.